# Lighttpd regex to redirect all pages matching a pattern except for one

Tags: regex, lighttpd

Using lighttpd I'm successfully redirecting all pages that begin with:

```
http://www.domain.com/cgi-bin/MDM/
```

to the corresponding secure version using this:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
   $HTTP["host"] == "www.domain.com" {
   url.redirect = ( "^/cgi-bin/MDM/(.*)" => "https://www.domain.com/$1" )
   }
}
```

and this works great. But now I've discovered one such page can't be served as HTTPS because of a 3rd party script that links to non-HTTPS elements. So I want to exclude that one page which is:

```
http://www.domain.com/cgi-bin/MDM/page.html
```

I've tried a number of things but can't seem to cook up the right rule. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have negative lookahead you can do "^/cgi-bin/MDM/(?!page\\.html)(.*)" to exclude a single page... if they become more it's not the way to go I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `!=` to exclude any URLs from redirecting:

```
$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
  $HTTP["host"] == "www.domain.com" {
    $HTTP["url"] != "/cgi-bin/MDM/page.html" {
      url.redirect = ( "^/cgi-bin/MDM/(.*)" => "https://www.domain.com/$1" )
    }
  }
}
```